# Echo a post by ID with retaining the paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress

Whenever I try to echo the content of a post I get the content without the html tags. Like paragraphs.

is there a way to echo them with paragraphs etc?

Right now this is my php code:

```
      $post_id = 1231;
      $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
      echo $queried_post->post_content;
```

Comment: Can you provide any example for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is how it looks like in on the actual page:
http://i60.tinypic.com/14jnlt5.png

But this is what I'm getting when I try to show the content of that page on another page:
http://i62.tinypic.com/11hgvgg.png

I read about applying filters, but with no luck. I have trouble to use it on my own example.

apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 $post_id = 1226;
 echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `the_content();` or `echo get_the_content();`

Because this function use the wp filter `the_content`, this filter use the 'wpautop' filters.

Which ads `p` tag

here is the snap

```
<?php
$post_id = 1226;
$post_local = get_post($post_id);
if($post_local){
    setup_postdata( $post_local );
    echo wpautop(get_the_content());
}
?>
```

Comment: When Im using it like this, nothing happens. Could you tell me what Im doing wrong? :) Thanks!
$post_id = 1226;
echo get_the_content($post_id)

Comment: this works for me, but this method may be a little outdated:

$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;

Comment: When I'm using the snap it still strips the P tags :/
Hmzz

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it, I have added wpautop function

Comment: I got an error with the wpautop function.

I got it working by using:
 $post_id = 1226;
                echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this to output content with html tags

```
echo str_replace("\r", "<br />", get_the_content(''));
```